# How to set a for -loop in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am a biologist and have less knowledge of programming. I have series of files(fasta format files) for which I need to apply an R package.

each file contents as follows:

FILE_1.FASTA

```
>>TTBK2_Hsap ,(CK1/TTBK)
MSGGGEQLDILSVGILVKERWKVLRKIGGGGFGEIYDALDMLTRENVALKVESAQQPKQVLKMEVAVLKKLQGKDHVCRFIGCGRNDRFNYVVMQLQGRNLADLRRSQSRGTFT
```

FILE_2.FASTA

```
>>TTBK2_Hsap ,(CK1/TTBK)
MSGGGEQLDILSVGILVKERWKVLRKIGGGGFGEIYDALDMLTRENVALKVESAQQPKQVLKMEVAVLKKLQGKDHVCRFIGCGRNDRFNYVVMQLQGRNLADLRRSQSRGTFT
```

and the package (protr in R) works like this:

```
x = readFASTA(system.file(’protseq/P00750.fasta’, package = ’protr’))[[1]]

extractAAC(x)
```

Is there any possibility to set a forloop for the above lines to read multiple files and give the output in one file??

If possible please give me some idea or any example which could help me set a for-loop in R.

Comment: You might want something like `lapply(dir(pattern='.fasta'), readFASTA)`, but I'm not familiar with this package so you might have to play around with the code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible to do this. A good strategy to use would be to write a function that encapsulates what you want to do with each FASTA file:

```
# fasta is a string that represents the fasta file to be read.
read_and_extract <- function(fasta){
    seq <- readFASTA(fasta)[[1]]
    return(extractAAC(seq))
}
```

This wrapper function will allow you to read the FASTA file and extract the amino acid composition all in one fell swoop. In order to loop over the files, we will need to be in the same directory as your FASTA files.

```
setwd("path/to/files")
```

Using the `dir` command, you can get all of the names of the files that exist in that directory.

```
fasta_files <- dir(pattern = "[.]fasta$")
```

Note that the `pattern` argument tells the computer to only read files that end with "`.fasta`"

Now we perform the loop using the `vapply` function (see note below for details):

```
aa_comp <- vapply(fasta_files, read_and_extract, rep(pi, 20))
```

This will produce a matrix with the columns being each fasta file and the rows being each amino acid. Now we can save this as a simple csv file:

```
write.csv(aa_comp, file = "amino_acid_composition.csv")
```

---

### Details of `vapply`

The `vapply` function is a fancy (and most times faster) way to do `for` loops in R. It looks a bit confusing at first, but it works very well if you know what your output will be. Let's look at the arguments:

> `> vapply(Argument1, Argument2, Argument3)`

- Argument1: The vector to be looped over (`fasta_files`)
- Argument2: The function to apply to each element of the vector (`read_and_extract`)
- Argument3: The expected output (`rep(pi, 20)`)

The last argument is the hardest to grasp initially, but it's a representative vector of our expected output. In this case, the documentation for `extractAAC` says that it returns a numeric vector of length 20. The command `rep(pi, 20)` is telling R to replicate the number `pi` 20 times, thus giving a numeric vector of length 20.

There are more generalized versions of `vapply` that can return output of any type. See `help("vapply")` for details on those.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful explaination... it worked like a charm :-)

Comment: can i make rows as fasta files and columns as amino acid composition?

Comment: Indeed you can! What you want to do is to [transpose the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). You can do that simply in R by using the function `t()` like so: `transposed_matrix <- t(your_matrix)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the straight forward for loop like this:

```
x <- list() # an empty list

for(f in yourFileList) {
  x[[which(yourFileList==f)]] <- readFASTA(system.file(f,package='protr'))[[1]]
}
```

You'll find more info under `?Control`

Answer (score 1):

There's two slightly complicated things here; one is the looping, and the other is writing all the results out to a file.

First off, if all you're trying to do is combine all your `fasta` files into one, its going to be much easier from your `bash` terminal than in `R`:

```
cat *.fasta > combined.fasta
```

But to answer your question for `R`, your loop could look something like this:

```
write("", file="combined.fasta")  # make sure the file exists before appending
for (fileName in dir(pattern='.fasta')) {
    x = readFASTA(system.file(fileName, package = ’protr’))[[1]]
    # do stuff to x
    write(x, file="combined.fasta", append=TRUE)
}
```