# Setting a loop in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have already discussed a similar type of a question in this following post

[How to set a for -loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223440/how-to-set-a-for-loop-in-r)

each file contents as follows:

FILE_1.FASTA

```
>>TTBK2_Hsap ,(CK1/TTBK)
MSGGGEQLDILSVGILVKERWKVLRKIGGGGFGEIYDALDMLTRENVALKVESAQQPKQVLKMEVAVLKKLQGKDHVCRFIGCGRNDRFNYVVMQLQGRNLADLRRSQSRGTFT
```

FILE_2.FASTA

```
>>TTBK2_Hsap ,(CK1/TTBK)
MSGGGEQLDILSVGILVKERWKVLRKIGGGGFGEIYDALDMLTRENVALKVESAQQPKQVLKMEVAVLKKLQGKDHVCRFIGCGRNDRFNYVVMQLQGRNLADLRRSQSRGTFT
```

However, there is another package in R which works like this:

```
extractAPAAC(x, props = c("Hydrophobicity", "Hydrophilicity"), lambda = 30,
w = 0.05, customprops = NULL)
```

I tried creating a function to run it for number of file sequences and the program looks like this

```
read_and_extract <- function(fasta) {
  seq <- readFASTA(fasta)[[1]]
  return(extractAPAAC(seq, props = c("Hydrophobicity", "Hydrophilicity"), lambda = 30,
             w = 0.05, customprops = NULL))

}

setwd("H:\\CC")
fasta_files <- dir(pattern = "[.]fasta$")
aa_comp <- vapply(fasta_files, read_and_extract, rep(pi, 80))
write.csv(aa_comp, file = "C:\\Users\\PAAC.csv")
```

This programs shows an error

Error: unexpected ',' in "w = 0.05,"

But I have given w=0.05 as of default value, could anyone tell me where is the actual problem?

Comment: When using external packages, please include them somewhere in your question (e.g. `library(protr)`).  Also, since `props=...`, `lambda=30`, `w=0.05` and `customprops=NULL` are all defaults, you don't need to pass them at all. `extractAPAAC(seq)`  is equivalent.  Please show the exact code you ran and the exact error message if you want us to help debug.

Comment: what happens when you simply run the extractAPAAC() function? do you get the same error when it's not embedded in your funtion? That would be where I would start.